# How to correctly resize with same aspect ratio of SVG using tailwind css

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, svg, tailwind-css

I can't figure out how to resize SVG image with same aspect ratio using tailwind css in React/Typescript project.

This is my part of SVG file, saying default width is 682, height is 466

```
<svg width="682" height="466" viewBox="0 0 682 466" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<rect x="1.24639" y="16.5296" width="196.93" height="132.024" rx="3.73918" stroke="#899A7C" stroke-opacity="0.2" stroke-width="2.49279"/>
```

Then I just simply declare SVG image as below

```
import MySVG from '@svg/my_svg.svg'
import s from './showSVG.module.css'

            <div className={s.svgContainer}>
                    <MySVG className={s.svg} />
            </div>
```

Then tailwind CSS is

```
.svgContainer {
    @apply aspect-w-1 aspect-h-1;
}

.svg {
    @apply w-full h-full object-contain;
}
```

This does not work and SVG image is now invisible from screen.
So I tried to add specific width and height in `.svg` as below

```
.svg {
    @apply w-full h-full object-contain;
    @apply w-[682px] h-[466px]; // I added specific SVG size here
}
```

Now, we can see SVG image in the screen but it just sticks with the same size and doesn't resize with same aspect ratio when changing the screen size.

What is the best way to achieve changing SVG size with same aspect ratio from default width and height?

Comment: @Ed Lucas. Your link is broken